# How to scale font and container's height in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have problem with properly scaling height of containers and font size in Xamarin.Forms.

1) The first problem is that I need to set static height in one of my containers but it looks different on different devices. I don't know exactly but suppose that problem can be caused by screen density. Should I scale height of my container somehow or Xamarin.Forms should handle this for me?

2) The second problem is that I need to set proper cross-platform font. Is there a way to Xamarin.Forms handle it for me or need I use Device.RuntimePlatform property to set this? Also as said here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts - named font sizes are not acceptable solution. For iPod I need to use micro, but on android the text is barely visible.

On emulator there are many weird things happen, topbar is way out of scale and entire look is zoomed. Is this my fault or maybe Xamarin is not such universal platform I thought?

Here is the code of my page:

```
<StackLayout>
    <SearchBar 
        VerticalOptions="Start"
        TextChanged="SearchBar_OnTextChanged"
        PlaceholderColor="#C0C0C0"></SearchBar>

    <ListView 
        BackgroundColor="#f2f2f2"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        ItemTapped="SelectProcedure"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell 
                    Text="{Binding Name}" 
                    TextColor="Black"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <StackLayout 
        BackgroundColor="White"
        HeightRequest="80"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">

        <Grid
            Padding="10,5,10,5"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                TextColor="Black"/>

            <telerikInput:RadButton 
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Padding="5,0,5,0"
                ImageSource="plus.png"/>

        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

And here are the screenshots for two devices I have and emulator:

Android 8.1

[image]

iPod touch 6

[image]

Android 8.1 (emulator)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried AbsoluteLayout with PositionProportional flag to set the button controls at the bottom instead of grid?

Also, try the new "Visual" property to get more uniform results across platforms and devices.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** You can set the `HeightRequest` grid as the percentage of screen height (for example 10%) .

```
<StackLayout 
        BackgroundColor="White"
        HeightRequest="{Binding stackHeight}"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
```

#### in Share Project App.xaml.cs

```
public static double ScreenWidth;
public static double ScreenHeight;
```

#### in Android MainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
   ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

   base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

   Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            
   global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("Shell_Experimental", "Visual_Experimental", "CollectionView_Experimental");
   global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

   App.ScreenWidth = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels/Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density; 
   App.ScreenHeight =Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels/Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density; 

   LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

#### in iOS

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    //...
    App.ScreenWidth = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
    App.ScreenHeight = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
    //...
}
```

#### in Code Behind or ViewModel

```
public double stackHeight { get; private set; }

//...

if(Device.RuntimePlatform=="iOS")
{
  stackHeight= App.ScreenHeight/5.0;
}
else
{
  stackHeight= App.ScreenHeight/20.0;
}
```

And for Custom Font in Xamarin.Forms , you can check https://xamarinhelp.com/custom-fonts-xamarin-forms/

Comment: I will try your solution next week. I am using Xamarin.Essentials to get MainDisplayInfo.

Comment: I need to change height of container specifically for ios. Your solution works but 10% of screen on huge screen is too much, but on ipod is too small.

Comment: I have updated the code , you set set it as you want .